# How do I compare two characters in a case-insensitive manner?

Tags: c

I am creating a simple [rock paper scissors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_paper_scissors) game in which I read two characters from standard input. Each of these characters should be one of the following: `'r'` (rock), `'p'` (paper) or `'s'` (scissors).

In order to determine the winner, I compare the characters like this:

```
if ( player1 == 'r' && player2 == 's' )
    printf( "Player-1 wins! Rock breaks scissors!\n" );
```

This comparison works properly if both characters are entered in lower-case. However, if either of the characters is upper-case (`'R'`, `'P'` or `'S'`), the comparison will not work properly. I want the comparison to be able to handle both lower-case and upper-case characters properly.

My idea is to make the comparison look something like this:

```
if ( player1 == 'r','R' && player2 == 's','S')
    printf( "Player-1 wins! Rock breaks scissors!\n" );
```

How do I perform this comparison properly?

Comment: You can use the function [`toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) or [`tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower) before doing the comparison.  For example `player1 = tolower( player1 );`

Comment: I have reformulated your question to make it clearer, hoping that it will attract more upvotes for you. Feel free to revert my changes if you don't like them.

Answer (score 1):

Use [this](https://linux.die.net/man/3/tolower) function: `tolower`, so every comparison you're going to make it with the letters being compared after converted to lowercase.

```
if (tolower(player1) == 'r' && tolower(players2) == 's')
```

Comment: The link you posted is to platform-specific documentation (Linux). However, the question is not tagged for any specific platform. Therefore, you may want to link to platform-neutral documentation instead, as I have done in my comment. Feel free to copy my link.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pair of functions from the header <ctype.h> that could help you out.

Those functions are: `tolower` and `toupper`. They take a char as parameter and returns this values as lowercase/uppercase respectively (If the char is not a letter it returns the value unchanged).

What you can do is convert to either upper or lowercase and compare with a single letter.

```
 if (tolower(player1) == 'r' && tolower(player2) == 's')
```

or

```
 if (toupper(player1) == 'R' && toupper(player2) == 'S')
```

This ways I told above takes less code and is easier to read.

However, if you don't want to use those functions, the following code is the fix you needed for the result you intended:

```
 if ((player1 == 'r' || player1 == 'R') && (player2 == 's' || player2 == 'S'))
```

Comment: The parameter of `tolower` and `toupper` is not a `char` but an `int` which should contain an `unsigned char` value (or `EOF`). Elements of the basic execution character set are nonnegative, but whatever the user typed is not necessarily such a character. So the calls should be `tolower((unsigned char) player1)`. Otherwise, if the user types a character that has a negative value, the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Are you saying that input functions such as `fgetc` can return negative values besides `EOF`?

Comment: Thank you, used the less easier to read version but it worked. Much appreciated!

Comment: @vmp would you be able to help me with something else in the same boat? I cannot ask another question because I am on timeout for 2 days because I formatted my first question wrong.

Comment: sure. what is it?

Comment: @vmp do you have a discord? It is a homework assignment that I can send, I am sure you can figure it out in 2 minutes.

Comment: No, I don't. Try asking here

Comment: @Nyosit: Before posting your question here, you might want to check whether you can post a new question in the standard manner. Meanwhile, I have edited your question to make it clearer, so that I felt that I could upvote it. Therefore, you may now be able to post a new question (especially if your previous question now gets upvoted by other people, too). However, I do suggest that you read the following page before posting your new question: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/12149471)

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: Standard library routines that return values for characters, like `fgetc`, return an `int` that contains `EOF` or the value of an `unsigned char`. But programmers commonly read with other methods, like `scanf("%c",…)` or `fread`. If you read with those into a `char` or `char` array, you can get negative values (if `char` is signed). Also, if you assign the result of `fgetc` to a `char`, you can get overflow, which is immediately behavior that is not defined by the C standard. Even if the assignments works and wraps, the behavior of the subsequent `tolower` call is not defined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Oh, you are right. At first I found this hard to believe, but [§7.4 ¶1 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4p1) clearly states that what you say is true. Thanks for pointing this out. I have learnt something today. I'm sure that I have written lots of buggy code in the past few years which I never noticed, probably due to the implementation being tolerant.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: Yes, the GNU C Library and likely others are tolerant. For the `<ctype.h>` functions, they accept values from −128 to 255, using a table with duplicated entries. I am not sure how `EOF` is affected. If it is defined as −1, it overlaps with a signed `char` value. And you would have to favor the correct result for `EOF`, which I think is “false” for all character type tests, so the −1 character could never produce “true” for any test.